# Could not find module in nix-shell

Tags: haskell, nix, nixos

What could be the reason for `missing module`?

```
$ nix-shell -p haskellPackages.ghc -p haskellPackages.random
```

give following shell

```
[nix-shell:~]$ ghci 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /data/works/dotfiles/ghci
Prelude> import System.Random

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

And **what is the `nix` way to install and use Haskell packages?**

I thought `nixos.haskellPackages.<package>` will automatically registered for ghc but it seem like it is not the case.

Reinstall the `random` inside the shell don't fix it.

```
[nix-shell:~]$ nix-env -iA nixos.haskellPackages.random
installing ‘random-1.1’

[nix-shell:~]$ ghc-pkg list | grep -i random
```

Comment: The nix way of using development packages is indeed to go through `nix-shell` like you did. There might be specific issues with Haskell: I would advise you to read the [Haskell section of the nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure) to learn more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of reasons why this doesn't work. But you could try this command:

```
nix-shell -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (pkgs: with pkgs; [random])"
```

Works for me. And now `ghci` sees `System.Random` package.

**UPDATE:**

This post is really helpful for beginners in their `nix + haskell` adventure:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170910171927/http://alpmestan.com/posts/2017-09-06-quick-haskell-hacking-with-nix.html

Comment: This method only work for `ghc` but not for `ghc-mod`; `$ nix-shell -p "haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (self: with self; [random ghc-mod])"`; I am so confuse about nixos haskell system.

Comment: I wrote an answer to another question where I explain why it didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45023011/450128  (the question itself isn't strictly a duplicate)

Comment: Shersh thank you for the helpful answer, your 'nix-shell' line there worked for me. Also, fyi that link to the post appears to be broken.

Comment: @mherzl I'm glad you liked the answer :) I've updated the link to the one from WebArchive.